# How to make a gameobject grow i a direction without growing equally in the opposite direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

So far i've made it point toward the cursor and grow on the y-axis whenever i press given button, problem is it grows 50% towards the cursor and 50% in the opposit direction. Here's the code ive got so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tunge : MonoBehaviour {

int x = 0;
bool vis = false;
public GameObject tungen;

public Animator doge;


void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

    doge.SetFloat ("tungelength", x);
    if (vis == true) 
    {
        tungen.SetActive(true);
    }

    if (vis == false) 
    {
        tungen.SetActive(false);

    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        vis = true;

        float flyt = 0.1f;
        tungen.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0, flyt, 0);

        x++;
    }

    if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0) && x > 0) 
    {
        float flyt = 0.1f;
        tungen.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0, -flyt, 0);

        x--;
    }

    if (x == 0) 
    {
        vis = false;         
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Normally it depends on the order of transformations. You should translate first, then scale.. Is it possible to change the order?

Answer (score 1):

You have to translate the object when scaled:

I have added some lines to your code, please check it out

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tunge : MonoBehaviour {

int x = 0;
bool vis = false;
public GameObject tungen;

public Animator doge;


void Start()
{

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

doge.SetFloat ("tungelength", x);
if (vis == true) 
{
    tungen.SetActive(true);
}

if (vis == false) 
{
    tungen.SetActive(false);

}

if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
{
    vis = true;

    float flyt = 0.1f;
    tungen.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0, flyt, 0);


    // ADD THIS LINE:
    tungen.transform.position += new Vector3( 0, flyt / 2, 0 );


    x++;
}

if (!Input.GetMouseButton (0) && x > 0) 
{
    float flyt = 0.1f;
    tungen.transform.localScale += new Vector3 (0, -flyt, 0);


    // ADD THIS LINE:
    tungen.transform.position += new Vector3( 0, -flyt / 2, 0 );


    x--;
}

if (x == 0) 
{
    vis = false;         
}
```

}
}